# unable to install JQ via PIP

Tags: python, python-2.7, jq

I am trying to install JQ via PIP in python.

```
pip install jq
```

I am getting following error.

**Failed building wheel for jq**

[image]

I am facing same issue while install pyjq.

```
pip install pyjq
```

**Failed building wheel for pyjq**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu 18.04, I needed to `apt-get install autoconf libtool` before my `pip install pyjq` would complete.

Comment: This worked for me, but @devanthan is using Windows.  The project homepage on PyPI (https://pypi.org/project/jq/) currently shows how to install the dependencies only on Linux and OS X.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't appear that jq supports Windows; it says it requires gcc & libtool, which generally means a Unix-like environment.

Answer (score 1):

Like you I had a difficult time installing jq

In my attempts I had many various errors including the failed building wheel that you are getting. I assume that the problem was on my end and not that the host was temporarily down. My setup: python 2 & 3, Jupyter, brew in addition to pip. The problem was likely due to some lack of consistency in package links, brew doctor helped me identify which links were broken then brew link/unlink/overwrite.

At anyrate I was only successful after brew uninstall jq, fixing all links, then updating brew and rebooting my system (perhaps some dependency was occupied?).

Then and only then did finally `pip install jq` work

Comment: "brew doctor" had a lot of complaints for me, and I fixed them. (Thanks! Didn't know "brew doctor" existed.) Now, although I can "brew install jq", but not "pip install pyjq" or "pipenv install" will a requirements file listing pyjq...

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced same issues as OP. Although in my case (Debian Stretch 9.5) it turned out `dh-autoreconf` package was missing. After installing it, `jq` build finished successfully.