# "pip install jq" generates errors on Mac and Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pip, jq

Duplicate of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785890/unable-to-install-jq-via-pip), but the first answer there is wrong (`jq` is supported on Windows) and the second refers to `brew` so I'm guessing is for Mac.

#### Windows

I am trying to install `jq` for python from the Windows command line, but get the following errors, possibly due to a missing `temp\pip-build-rtnhmg\jq\onig-install-5.9.6` file:
`error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`
... and ...

> `Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\<USERNAME>\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-rtnhmg\\jq\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\<USERNAME>\appdata\local\temp\pip-khvjht-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\<USERNAME>\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-rtnhmg\jq\`

Does anyone know what's gone wrong here?  Searches on StackOverflow and Google aren't giving me much to go on, and I'm not great with Windows and still new to python/pip.

Here is the full text, minus username:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install jq
Collecting jq
  Using cached jq-0.1.6.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: jq
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for jq ... error
  Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\<USERNAME>\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-rtnhmg\\jq\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\<USERNAME>\appdata\local\temp\tmpuvrf_upip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  Executing: ./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC --prefix=c:\users\<USERNAME>\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-rtnhmg\jq\onig-install-5.9.6
  error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for jq
  Running setup.py clean for jq
Failed to build jq
Installing collected packages: jq
  Running setup.py install for jq ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\<USERNAME>\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-rtnhmg\\jq\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\<USERNAME>\appdata\local\temp\pip-khvjht-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    Executing: ./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC --prefix=c:\users\<USERNAME>\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-rtnhmg\jq\onig-install-5.9.6
    error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\<USERNAME>\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-rtnhmg\\jq\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\<USERNAME>\appdata\local\temp\pip-khvjht-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\<USERNAME>\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-rtnhmg\jq\
```

Trying to install pyjq instead generates the same errors.

I'm not married to jq: I just need to format json data in python, and jq does a great job on the command line.  If there are other python packages I should try instead, please feel free to recommend them.  As mentioned above though, pyjq is failing install with the same errors.

**Further details / steps taken:**

- I am on Windows 10 and have installed python 2.7.13, `setuptools` and `pip` using [the steps from here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/) ... no issues noted.
- Using pip, I have successfully installed other python packages such as request and jira ... no issues noted.
- Using chocolatey I have successfully installed jq for the command line, following [these steps](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation) ... no issues noted.
- I have tried using regular permissions, running cmd as administrator, starting a new cmd session, restarting the PC - but get the same errors.
- Trying to install pyjq (`pip install pyjq`) generates the same errors.
- Tried `pip install jq` on a Mac and got similar errors:

  > `Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/v5/4x0py0ns2td1h69vgllx7dpr0000gn/T/pip-build-DyMoT4/jq/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/v5/4x0py0ns2td1h69vgllx7dpr0000gn/T/pip-i6UKvt-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/v5/4x0py0ns2td1h69vgllx7dpr0000gn/T/pip-build-DyMoT4/jq/`
- for the Mac, followed the steps suggested from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498495/error-when-installing-using-pip) and successfully installed `setuptools` as suggested, but `pip install jq` still fails with the same error.

Comment: if someone hits a problem with installing jq on Mac OS, check whether you have all the prerequisites installed: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jq

Answer (score 11):

#### Installing via `pip`

As per [`jq` installation steps](https://pypi.org/project/jq/) for `pip`'s project:

> Installation requires any programs required to build `jq`. This includes:
>
> - Autoreconf
> - The normal C compiler toolchain, such as gcc and make.
> - `libtool`
> - Python headers.

#### macOS

On macOS, you need XCode to be installed, and the following packages:

```
brew install autoconf automake libtool
brew install jq
```

#### Linux

You need the following packages to be installed:

```
yum install autoconf automake libtool python
```

Comment: ditto on windows solution?

Answer (score 0):

To install the `jq` Python module on Windows, you can follow these steps:

1. Install `jq` executable:

   - Download the Windows executable for `jq` from the official repository: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases.
   - Choose the appropriate version (e.g., `jq-win64.exe` for 64-bit Windows).
   - Save the executable file to a location on your computer (e.g., `C:\jq\jq-win64.exe`).
2. Add `jq` executable to the system's PATH:

   - Press `Win + X` and select "System" or "System Properties."
   - Click on "Advanced system settings" on the left.
   - In the "System Properties" window, click on the "Environment Variables" button.
   - In the "Environment Variables" dialog, locate the "Path" variable in the "System variables" section and select it.
   - Click on the "Edit" button.
   - Click on the "New" button and enter the directory path where the `jq` executable is located (e.g., `C:\jq`).
   - Click "OK" on all open dialogs to save the changes.