# Multiple errors trying to install jq

Tags: python, jq

```
%pip install jq
```

returns the following error

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\myacn\anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\myacn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\myacn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpygza7t_7'
       cwd: C:\Users\myacn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l6yh1hi9\jq
  Complete output (7 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  Downloading https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/releases/download/v6.9.4/onig-6.9.4.tar.gz
  Downloaded https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/releases/download/v6.9.4/onig-6.9.4.tar.gz
  Executing: ./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC --prefix=C:\Users\myacn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l6yh1hi9\jq\_deps\onig-install-6.9.4
  error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for jq
ERROR: Could not build wheels for jq which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Looking online this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262960/pip-install-jq-generates-errors-on-mac-and-windows) resolves for mac and linux, I'm not entirely familiar with the right installation for windows, trying `%pip install autoconf automake libtool` gives

```
Collecting autoconf
  Using cached autoconf-0.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement automake (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for automake
Collecting jq
  Using cached jq-1.1.1.tar.gz (69 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: jq
  Building wheel for jq (PEP 517): started
  Building wheel for jq (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build jq
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
LOAD DURATION:  0:00:11.548563
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\myacn\anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\myacn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\myacn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpygza7t_7'
       cwd: C:\Users\myacn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l6yh1hi9\jq
  Complete output (7 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  Downloading https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/releases/download/v6.9.4/onig-6.9.4.tar.gz
  Downloaded https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/releases/download/v6.9.4/onig-6.9.4.tar.gz
  Executing: ./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC --prefix=C:\Users\myacn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l6yh1hi9\jq\_deps\onig-install-6.9.4
  error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for jq
ERROR: Could not build wheels for jq which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Seems like automake was the issue.

Reading another thread [here](https://github.com/pydata/bottleneck/issues/281), the error message is slightly different: the link talks about bottleneck, but mine does not. Going through that thread I first tried downgrading pip `pip install pip==18.1`, restarted kernel,

Here's the new errror:

```
  Failed building wheel for jq
Command "C:\Users\myacn\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\myacn\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m3mejes3\\jq\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\myacn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_38z9t11\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\myacn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m3mejes3\jq\
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 20.3b1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I then downloaded Visual Studio, specifically checking C++ install tools like the steps indicated; I tried re-running with updated pip and 18.1, and get the same errors.

Comment: The package doesn't seem to have been built to support Windows. Unless you are familiar with porting C++ code between different architectures and toolchains, probably just abandon this effort for now.

Comment: thanks for the information tripleee, this is for a graded assignment :(

or, if anyone might know, is there an equivalent package on windows? as I interpret jq is just a json reader

Comment: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/ has Windows binaries...

Comment: But this is for Python bindings to the library. If you are just looking for the command-line tool, indeed, install that from Stedolan. `pip` is for installing Python libraries, nothing else.

Comment: thanks Shawn, the executables said they should just run, but they didn't

so I installed the package with chocolatey, and cmd reads:

 "The install of jq was successful.
  Software install location not explicitly set, could be in package or
  default install location if installer.

Chocolatey installed 1/1 packages."

Now when I try importing jq in Jupyter I still get the same error no module named 'jq'. Thanks for getting me this close, just a little push across the finish line.

Comment: I think you're confused between Python modules and chocolatey modules. The two aren't the same--pip is a package manager for Python modules, chocolatey is a package manager for Windows apps. If you install it with chocolatey, you can run it in powershell or command but you can't import it as if it's a Python module. Install it with pip if you want a Python module, install it with chocolatey if you want a command line utility.

Comment: "jq is just a JSON reader" -- possibly you have an xy problem? jq is far more than just a JSON reader--it's a well-featured programming language for manipulating JSON structures. If you just need to "read" JSON, maybe `import json` and `json.loads(s)`? What are you trying to achieve that you need jq for? Having said that, I was able to reproduce the install error you saw on my Windows machine, so it's a legitimate problem.